# SSRS - hide subreports in report manager using code

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

we have 4 subreports and they are available from one main report. On deploying it is deploying 4 subreports and a main report. Is there a way to hide sub reports in code?

Comment: I usually hide manually the sub reports in report manager (after deploying). I am interested to know, if there is a code for it.

Comment: Are you asking if you can add a setting to the rdl file itself to cause the report to be hidden once deployed?  I don't believe so.  And as far as I know, you can't hide when deploying from VS or using the Upload button in Report Manager.  If you're deploying using RS.exe, however, this can be achieved.